# How can I show in django list of records from db

Tags: python, html, django

Can anybody help me? I have a list of 60 records from django database in my html file. I want to show that list in table of 6 columns and 10 rows. In html file I used command {% for %} but the list is in one column.

My html file is:

```
{% for kategoria in kategorie %} 
<table> 
  <tr> 
    <th> <a href="#">{{ kategoria.glowna|linebreaksbr }} </a> ({{ wpisy_kat }}) </th> 
  </tr> 
</table> 
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: You should elaborate it more , by putting what you have tried , they way it is asked is too generic

Comment: My html file is: 
{%  for kategoria in kategorie %}

<table>
<tr>
<th>
<a href="#">{{ kategoria.glowna|linebreaksbr }} </a>({{ wpisy_kat }}) 
</th>
</tr>
</table>
{%  endfor %} but this view is showing me only the one list. I want to display the list of records from Kategorie class on the table how I wrote in 6 columns and 10 rows without paginate.

Comment: please post your view-method or class. If it is a list view try `{% for kategoria in objects %}`

Comment: This is part od view file : def widok_kategorii(request):
    kategorie = Kategorie.objects.all()
    wpisy_kat = Kategorie.objects.count()
    return render(request, 'firmy/widok_kategorii.html', {'kategorie': kategorie, 'wpisy_kat': wpisy_kat})

Comment: @killerbees see my answer if it is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

you can try using `divisibleby` template tag in your template like this to change row after every six entries.

remember `{{ forloop.counter }}` {# starting index 1 #} and `{{ forloop.counter0 }}` {# starting index 0 #}

```
 {% for kategoria in kategorie %} 
    <table> 
     {% if not forloop.counter0 |divisibleby:"6" %}
      <tr> 
     {% endif %}
        <th> <a href="#">{{ kategoria.glowna|linebreaksbr }} </a> ({{ wpisy_kat }}) </th> 
    {% if forloop.counter|divisibleby:"6" %}
      </tr> 
    {% endif %}

</table> 
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<table>
 {% for object in queryset %}
   <tr>
     <td> object.attr1 </td>
     <td> object.attr2 </td>
     <td> object.attr3 </td>
     <td> object.attr4 </td>
     <td> object.attr5 </td>
     <td> object.attr6 </td>
   </tr>
 {% endfor %}
</table>
```

If you want to have a more pages with 10 items each page, have a look at django's [pagination](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/pagination/)